# Table cells are not separated

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I have created a table in HTML. When I took a look at the page I noticed that the cells are not separated. I couldn't find any solutions on Google. That's how it looks like :

[image: My Problem]

Here is the code I have used :

```
<table style="margin-top:50px;border:2px solid red;border-collapse:collapse;">

    <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean with separated?, if you delete `border-collapse:collpase;` it will be more separated.

Answer (score 2):

Add `padding` and `borders` to the `tr` and `td` elements.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NHU7t/)

```
td {padding:10px; border-right:1px solid orange;}
tr { border-bottom:1px solid blue }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for: [Padding in TD](http://jsfiddle.net/tZNw4/37/)

```
td {
    padding: 20px;
}
```